# Allowing access to api only from local server

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I want to protect my `api` from being used by other people. I want to use api in my `JS` code(vue), but what if someone look into page source and will find `url` to `api`? Then he can do something like `page.com/api/add.php?name=test` and he can now put many rows into my database by using simple `url`, which I don't want. Is it possible to allow only access to `/api/` folder only when my server request to it?

Comment: JS runs on the client side so you're basically saying you want to be the only client to be able to use your API. What you want is authentication and authorisation checks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header so that your server will only allow access from the origins you specify. You can put this at the top of your php file.

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myserver.com', false);`

Comment: I still have access to api from my browser.

Comment: What if i will protect access to server by using ip-whitelist (firewall or something)?